# Cannot delete slf4j dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, slf4j

I have a problem with slf4j dependencies.

On POM.xml, i declared this:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>   
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>               
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>       
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i meet this error message:

```
   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
   SLF4J: Found binding in               
   [jar:file:/C:/Users/r.rossi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-
   nop/1.5.3/slf4j-nop-1.5.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   SLF4J: Found binding in 
   [jar:file:/C:/Users/r.rossi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-
    jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-
    1.5.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in 
    [jar:file:/C:/Users/r.rossi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-
    log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-
    1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
     SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an 
    explanation.
    SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
    SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
    SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x.
```

On those directorties and on maven dependencies i have  1.5 versions but i don't have them on POM.xml file (as you can see), so i don't know how delete them. If i delete the directories, it works but the next esecution the project download again the 1.5 versions. How can i delete those damned 1.5 versions?

Comment: have you tried to clean your build before executing and cleaning your repository cache?

Answer (score 3):

As the error stack suggest check the link [Multiple Binding](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings).
Also, check [Dependency Tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) to check which external dependency is trying to include (1.5.5 or earlier version). 
Basically, your exclusion code

```
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>               
   </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

should be inserted inside that dependency which depends on an earlier version 1.5.5.